# Catalina's Terminal "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-catalina

I start to use Catalina macOS but there is a problem with the terminal, the terminal shows this message.

```
> [forkpty: Resource temporarily unavailable][Could not create a new
> process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

Answer (score 1):

From Terminal--> Preferences-->Shells will open with + Default login shell.

And restart your's Mac.